# export_graphviz and visualising a DT

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am using the following code in a 'text' binary classification problem:

```
def visualize_tree(tree,feature_names):
    dot_data = StringIO() 
    export_graphviz(tree,
                    out_file=dot_data,
                    feature_names=feature_names,
                    special_characters=True)          
    graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue(),) 
    graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf") 

vec = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, tokenizer=tokens2, binary=True, ngram_range=(1,2))   
x = vec.fit_transform(X_train)
clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf1.fit(x, y_train)    
visualize_tree(clf1, vec.get_feature_names())
```

When I use it **without** `feature_names=feature_names,` it will generate a beautiful tree like this one: 
[image]

However, when I add `feature_names=feature_names,` to add extra details to the tree, it gives me the following 'semi tree'!:

[image] 
All in one line without any arrows! Any idea why? Are there any alternative ways I can try?

Comment: very strange, can you create a minimal example for where this happens ? does it still happen if you set `max_depth = 2` in `DecisionTreeClassifier`?

Comment: It doesn't construct a tree even when I set max_depth = 2 in the DecisionTreeClassifier !

Comment: can you try changing `out_file='tree.dot'` and then generating the pdf from the command line using `'dot -Tpdf tree.dot -o tree.pdf'`?

Comment: Yes ! Perfect ... Cannot thank you enough .. Just another question what does( features<=0.5 ) on the tree indicates ? And please put your previous comment as an answer so I can vote and accept :)

Comment: since your features are binary, "<=0.5" actually means "==0", if you want to have a better visualisation you might want to write a script to replace this in the outputfile, e.g. something like `f = open('tree.dot'); s = f.read().replace("<=0.5","==0"); f.close(); f.open('tree.dot','r'); f.write(s); f.close()`

Comment: or better still do this on the `StringIO` that you have already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `pydot`, you can just use graphviz from the command line, if you want to be fancy you can call it from your code with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

export_graphviz(model,
                out_file='tree.dot',
                feature_names=feature_names)

subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'tree.dot', '-o' 'tree.pdf'])
```